# Is UDP a layer 4 protocol?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, ip, protocols

I'm currently acting under the following assumptions but I'm not able to connect the dots. Can someone please correct these assumptions?

1. The protocol that will be used in the Transport Layer (Layer 4) is identified as the "protocol" in the IP header
2. You never actually specify whether or not you will be using TCP or UDP. The protocol that you will be using is simply either implemented in UDP or TCP
3. In the Transport Layer's header, it will be a UDP header if the protocol specified in the IP header uses UDP and it will have a TCP header if the protocol uses TCP.

If this is the case then what are TCP and UDP classified as? I originally thought they were protocols that you would choose to use but when I look at the IP header, it dedicates 7 bits to the protocol so that just doesn't make sense.

Why aren't protocols such as SSH and FTP able to be selected in the IP header? According to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers), they aren't options.

It's difficult for me to verbally explain where I'm confused. I'm just trying to see exactly how everything connects. Hopefully someone can see where I'm confused and clear it up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP and TCP are two protocols in the Transport Layer, and there are others. SSH and FTP are protocols in the Application Layer; they are carried inside transport-layer protocols (these two protocols use TCP).

Comment: How is it possible for other protocols in the Transport Layer to also use UDP/TCP?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Which transport-layer protocols do you mean use UDP/TCP?

Comment: Doesn't SMTP use UDP/TCP?

Comment: SMTP is an application-layer protocol.

Comment: @ChristopherRussell, think about it this way. the client/server concept is an application concept, so protocols that implement that are application-layer protocols. If you look at the protocols at or below the the Transport Layer, they are all peer-to-peer protocols.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up for me. What about the Layer 2 protocol? Why is it that we never explicitly say we will be using "IP" in the Ethernet header? On a side note, is the Transport Layer header found inside of the "Data" portion of the Network Layer?

Comment: "_Why is it that we never explicitly say we will be using "IP" in the Ethernet header?_" The ethernet header has the Ether Type field that tells it where to send the payload. IPv4 is one type, IPv6 is another. There are a lot of different Ether Types. The full transport PDU, including any header, is the payload of the layer-3 packet.